# Can't find proguad mapping file

Tags: android, proguard

I have enable proguard, but for tracking bugs I need a mapping file to upload to Google Play.
Here is my gradle configuration of proguard:

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Comment: `app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt`

Answer (score 0):

try to find the mapping file at `build/outputs/proguard/release/mapping.txt` in your application module's directory.

if you have `-dontobfuscate` in your proguard. please remove it
rebuild and rerun.. Then it should able to see the mapping file in proguard directory

Comment: and lint-results-debug-fatal and thats it

Comment: I have  proguard-android.txt-2.2 file , maybe its what I need? in intermediates folder